# Complicated sql query - select all landlords' properties and subtract costs in one query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a table data structure similar to this:

**Landlord table**

````````````````````````
Id    Name        Email
```````````````````````
1     J Johnson    ...
2     R Kelly      ...
````````````````````````

**Property table**

````````````````````````````````````
Id    Address    Rent    LandlordId
```````````````````````````````````
1    ....        400    1
2    ....        600    1
3    ....        750    2
````````````````````````````````````

**Maintenance table**

``````````````````````````````````````````````````````
Id    Details   Cost    MaintenanceDate    PropertyId
`````````````````````````````````````````````````````
1    ....        25     20/12/2012         1
2    ....        120    22/12/2012         2
3    ....        35     24/12/2012         3
``````````````````````````````````````````````````````

Essentially, a Landlord has multiple properties.. Each month, I need to produce an invoice for the landlord which includes all his properties, all the maintenance done on his property. To calculate how much I need to pay to the landlord, I need to sum all his properties' Rent and subtract that with the sum of all his maintenance costs for that month.

So, *amount payable to landlord L = Sum(Rent of properties of L) - Sum(maintenance costs on all properties of L during this month)*

I am using telerik reporting, thought I could achieve it with some clever grouping but that was a waste of my time so I am now going to try and achieve this with SQL and sub reports instead.

The SQL query that I'm trying is this:

```
 SELECT l.Name, p.[Address], p.Rent, c.Details, c.Cost,
(select Rent From Property where Id = p.Id) - 
    (select SUM(cost) from CarriedOutJobs where PropertyId = p.Id) 
    as PayableToLandlord
FROM Landlord l JOIN PROPERTY p ON p.LandlordId = l.Id
LEFT OUTER JOIN Maintenance c ON c.PropertyId = p.Id
ORDER BY l.Fullname
```

This doesn't seem to work properly as it produces multiple fields

Because I am going to breakup the report into sub report, I thought I would just get landlord details first but I still need to calculate the amount payable to Landlord even in this case.. So I rewrote the query to this:

```
SELECT distinct l.Name,
(SELECT SUM(Rent) FROM PROPERTY WHERE LandlordId = l.Id) - 
    (SELECT COALESCE(SUM(cost), 0)
    FROM CarriedOutJobs WHERE PropertyId = p.Id) AS     PayableToLandlord
FROM Landlord l 
JOIN PROPERTY p ON p.LandlordId = l.Id 
ORDER BY l.Fullname
```

I thought this worked okay, but even though I have used distinct, this seems to produce a duplicate row with different `PayableToLandlord` amount and I can't seem to figure out why.

Is there a way to select all landlords, their properties, and the amount payable to them in one query, please?

I have removed date where clause for the sake of simplicity here.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suggest keep it simple and use sub-queries as these are easy to work out what's going on.  Hopefully you can then do your subtraction etc either in the report or quite simply as additional return columns.
Any date parameters you should pass in as variables in to the sub-queries (probably).

```
SELECT Landlord.Id as LandlordId, Landlord.Name, 
       ISNULL(TotalRent,0) AS TotalRent, 
       ISNULL(TotalCost,0) AS TotalCost
FROM Landlord
LEFT JOIN 
    (SELECT SUM(Rent) as TotalRent, LandLordId 
     FROM Property
     GROUP BY LandLordId) Rents
ON Landlord.Id = Rents.LandlordId
LEFT JOIN 
    (SELECT LandLordId,SUM(Cost) AS TotalCost
     FROM Property
     INNER JOIN Maintenance
        ON Property.Id = Maintenance.PropertyId
     GROUP BY LandLordId
     ) MaintenanceCosts
ON Landlord.Id = MaintenanceCosts.LandlordId
ORDER BY Landlord.Name
```

Just noticed you also wrote:

> Is there a way to select all landlords, their properties, and the amount payable to them in one query, please?

You can further join in the list of properties but you'll end up repeating the sum on each line.  This is fine as long as you don't try to SUM it within your reporting package.

If you do want the property details then my suggestion is to pull in each property rent and cost and then do the SUM / net figure in the reporting package.

Comment: Hi, this looks great, I am thinking I can try have a sub-report and populate property details with that and it should be okay.. One question, however.. isn't sub query a bad idea? This particular project is just a homebrewed solution for a friend of mine (I still don't know how he convinced me to write this up for him for free) and it will never be dealing with more than probably 100 landlords and 100 properties (1 per landlord) but even so, I find subqueries drain a lot of time...

Comment: There's nothing inherently bad about using sub-queries.  Afterall it's the same as putting that portion in to a view and querying that.  For the amount of data you're playing with you'd have to do something really dumb for it not to work out fine.  The query optimiser is your friend.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a shorter query: Please comment.

```
select l.name, x.propid,
sum(x.tot) as finalrent
from landlord l
left join
(select p.landlordid, (p.rent - m.cost) as tot,
p.id as propid 
from property p left join 
maintenance m
on p.id = m.propertyid) as x
on
l.id = x.landlordid
group by l.id, x.propid
;


NAME        PROPID  FINALRENT
J Johnson   1       375
J Johnson   2       480
R Kelly     3       715
```

25/12/2012

---

### Edit to add SQLFIDDLE as well as results `group by landlord only`

Query shows Total rent after cost is deducted.

- [SQLFIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5d75f/2)

Query:

```
-- group by landlord only

select l.id, l.name,
sum(x.tot) as finalrent, 
sum(COALESCE(x.cost,0)) as TotalCost
from landlord l
left join
(select p.landlordid, 
(p.rent - COALESCE(m.cost,0)) as tot,
p.id as propid, m.cost 
from property p left join 
maintenance m
on p.id = m.propertyid) as x
on l.id = x.landlordid
group by l.id
;
```

Results:

```
ID  NAME        FINALRENT   TOTALCOST
1   R Johnson   880         120
2   R Kelly     715         35
```

27/12/2012

Comment: Hi, in your query, if there hasn't been any maintenance costs to a property, the rent is calculated as ``NULL``, and it also has duplicates..

Comment: @Alexander Thanks for commenting. This query is `grouped by both landloard id and property id`, so it will show all properties under ond landlord. If no `maintenance cost`, it will show you only the `rent`.

Comment: So I can coalesce, I guess? I'm trying that now

Comment: Indeed :) here is the [SQLFIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/50890/1) Which I forgot to add to the answer the other day ;) So I added a `null` for one of the `costs` then it tests and shows your the results taking `COALESCE` into account.

Answer (score 0):

Joel's answer is very good.  There is, however, a somewhat simpler way to express this.  You can do the summaries in the subqueries at the *property* level, and then summarize at the landlord level in the outer query:

```
SELECT l.Id as LandlordId, l.Name, 
       sum(p.rent) as TotalRent,
       coalesce(sum(p.rent), 0) AS TotalRent, 
       coalesce(sum(m.PropertyCost), 0) AS TotalCost
FROM Landlord l left outer join
     Property p
     on l.LandlordId = p.LandlordId left outer join
     (SELECT PropertyId, SUM(Cost) AS PropertyCost
      FROM Maintenance m
      group by PropertyId
     ) m
     on m.PropertyId = p.PropertyId
group by l.LandLordId, l.LandlordName
ORDER BY Landlord.Name
```

This saves a join in the second subquery.

Comment: Hi, somehow it keeps saying "cost not found", twice and I can't figure out why it's doing that, even though I know that cost is a valid column! the actual error message: ``Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 4 Invalid column name 'Cost'.`` and this is repeated twice. (Same line too!)

Comment: Next to my queries, I ran Gordon's query on [SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/50890/9) there were few typos :) In my query could could also see that the answer for Total rent is shows the one minus any costs.